# MySQL and NULL datetime fields [again] ... populating query with str_replace

Tags: php, mysql

I've seen lots of good answers in general to the problem of `NULL` datetime fields, and the answer is don't use '', just put `NULL` directly.

That's all great, but all my MySQL queries are built up by doing a str_replace, like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM @@t1 WHERE @@f1=@@v1"
```

I then use table, field and value arrays with the actual content that will be replaced in

For every thing else it works 100% great 
For this I can't find a way of getting a `NULL` in there without quotes around it
Anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: you seem to be reinventing bound  Params \ Prepared Statements - not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use str_replace for constructing sql because actually it doesn't work 100% of the time.

Use **prepared statements** instead
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

**An example of where str_replace fails**

What if your table name, field name or data contains one of those "@@" tokens?  Then you are in trouble because it could get replaced with parameters, depending on what order you do your replacements.

With prepared statements the database handles all of this for you.  You also get automatic escaping done correctly, query precompilation for better performance and other security protection that you and I probably haven't even thought about.